# How to integrate twitter with c++ application?

Tags: c++, windows-7, twitter, sms, alert

I have a C++ application that uses curl to go to log in to a website, get information, and then parse the information.  Now I want to send myself an alert to my phone via sms or e-mail or I can I also send the alert to twitter and then get a notification that way.

My environment is windows vista and I use MSVS 8.

I just need something easy that i can throw together quick to notify myself when something on the webpage changes.

If there's anything that will work with curl (POST/GET), even better because I am already familiar with that.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Twitcurl](http://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/) provides a Twitter API on top of cURL.